# How to mirror or flip a CVImageBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-video

I know mirroring can be set during session configuration, but assume this is not viable for this particular project, can it still be done efficiently when `CVImageBuffer` is already obtained?

```
// To set mirroring when setting up
let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)!.isVideoMirrored = true
videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)!.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
```

Answer (score -1):

If your question is simply how to flip a CVImageBuffer, then three options are that you can use Metal, Core Image, or the Accelerate framework.

Core Image is probably preferable. Create a CIContext, and a CIImage with the buffer and use imageByApplyingTransform. Render that resulting CIImage back to an image buffer.